# Kafka，Why is partition always 0? Whether I set key or not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

```
public void testKafka() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic1","zxcvb", String.valueOf(i));
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
}
```

---

```
    @Component
class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "01",topics = "topic1")
    public void onMessage1(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        System.out.println("1============" + record.topic() + "->" + record.partition() + "->" + record.value() + "============");
    }
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "02", topicPartitions = {
            @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = {"2"})
    })
    public void onMessage2(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        System.out.println("2============" + record.topic() + "->" + record.partition() + "->" + record.value() + "============");
    }
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "03", topicPartitions = {
            @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = {"3"})
    })
    public void onMessage3(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        System.out.println("3============" + record.topic() + "->" + record.partition() + "->" + record.value() + "============");
    }
}
```

---

Above is my code, I don't know why partition is always 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/761bF.png)

If I set the key, it is still 0
If I use `send (string topic, integer partition, K key, @ nullable V data)`

Error: `Topic topic1 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always send records with the same key to the same partition - that is by design. See the `DefaultPartitioner`:

```java
/**
 * The default partitioning strategy:
 * <ul>
 * <li>If a partition is specified in the record, use it
 * <li>If no partition is specified but a key is present choose a partition based on a hash of the key
 * <li>If no partition or key is present choose the sticky partition that changes when the batch is full.
 * 
 * See KIP-480 for details about sticky partitioning.
 */
public class DefaultPartitioner implements Partitioner {
```

The error probably means you are trying to send to a partition that doesn't exist.